# Problem in populating list object when trying to compare 2 list object

Tags: c#

I am trying to compare 2 Subvariants data at a time and then based on that prepare results as follows :

```
Subvariants[0]  -   Subvariants[1]

Subvariants[1]  -   Subvariants[2]
.
.
so on
```

Lets say below is the outcome of comparing above subvariant list :

```
Subvariants[0]  -   Subvariants[1] = Success

Subvariants[1]  -   Subvariants[2] = Error
```

Now since processing `Subvariants[0]  -   Subvariants[1] is success` so i want to populate my `AggregateResults with 2 records`(**Subvariants[0],Subvariants[1]**) but Subvariants[1]  -   Subvariants[2] has error so i want to populate my AggregateResults with only 1 record containing Subvariants[2] `Name and ErrorMessage` info with `Success` property value as false.

But here the problem is how do i capture the AggregateResults for Subvariants in catch section which has got error ?

**Code :**

```
public class Aggregate
{
    public string Name { get; internal set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; internal set; }
    public bool Success { get; internal set; } = true;
    //other properties
}

public class ExecutionResult
{
    public string VariantName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<AggregateStats> AggregateResults { get; set; }
}

public class Variant
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Subvariants> Subvariants { get; set; }
}

public class Subvariants
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public ExecutionResult GetExecutionResult(Variant model)
    {
        var executionResult = new ExecutionResult();
        executionResult.Name = model.VariantName;
        var aggregateResults = new List<AggregateStats>();
        try
        {
            for (int counter = 0; counter < model.Subvariants.Count - 1; counter++)
            {
                var left = model.Subvariants[counter];
                var right = model.Subvariants[counter + 1];
                using (var t = new AggregateCalculator(model))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                    {
                        if (i == 0)
                        {
                            t.Start(i);
                            if (counter == 0)
                            {
                                aggregateResults.Add(new AggregateStats
                                {
                                    Name = left.Name,
                                    //other properties
                                });
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            t.Start(i);
                            aggregateResults.Add(new AggregateStats
                            {
                                Name = right.Name,
                                //other properties
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            aggregateResults.AggregateResults = aggregateResults.AsReadOnly();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        return executionResult;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Matti Price is right about the `try-catch` location. That being said, here's an other option: using an enumerator. This is *in my opinion* easier to read and maintain. It also ensures code is not duplicated (I've made methods to separate duplicated code and pass parameters instead). On top of that, you don't need a `List` to keep track of your results.

```
public ExecutionResult GetExecutionResult(Variant model)
{
    return new ExecutionResult
    {
        Name = model.VariantName,
        AggregateResults = CaclulateAggregates(model);
    };
}

private IEnumerable<AggregateStats> CaclulateAggregates(Variant model)
{
    for (int counter = 0; counter < model.Subvariants.Count - 1; counter++)
    {
        try
        {
            var left = model.Subvariants[counter];
            var right = model.Subvariants[counter + 1];

            using (var t = new AggregateCalculator(model))
            {
                if (counter == 0)
                {
                    t.Start(0);
                    yield return CreateStats(left.Name);
                }

                t.Start(1);
                yield return CreateStats(left.Name);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            yield return CreateStats(left.Name);
            yield break;
        }
    }
}

private AggregateStats CreateStats(string name)
{
    return new AggregateStats
    {
        Name = name,
        //other properties (add parameters)
    }
}
```

One caveat (or a note), is that the enumerator won't be *fully* executed until the first access to `ExecutionResult.AggregateResults`. I personally prefer this since the consumer of `ExecutionResult` might only want to have the first `AggregateStats`. In this case only the first will be computed which is handy (again, *in my opinion*). It all depends on *how* you consume your results.

If you want to compute them all at once before returning the results, you could also change `CaclulateAggregates(model)` to `CaclulateAggregates(model).ToArray()` which will compute the whole enumeration and create an array with it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to move your try-catch block inside your `for` loop so that it has the counter context and can access/figure out the data that you need to assign in your error object. Something like this:

```
public ExecutionResult GetExecutionResult(Variant model) {
            var executionResult = new ExecutionResult();
            executionResult.Name = model.VariantName;
            var aggregateResults = new List<AggregateStats>();

            for(int counter = 0; counter < model.Subvariants.Count - 1; counter++) {
                var left = model.Subvariants[counter];
                var right = model.Subvariants[counter + 1];
                try {
                    using(var t = new AggregateCalculator(model)) {
                        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                            if(i == 0) {
                                t.Start(i);
                                if(counter == 0) {
                                    aggregateResults.Add(new AggregateStats {
                                        Name = left.Name,
                                        //other properties
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                t.Start(i);
                                aggregateResults.Add(new AggregateStats {
                                    Name = right.Name,
                                    //other properties
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception ex) {
                    aggregateResults.Add(new AggregateStats {
                        Name = left.Name,
                        //other error props
                    });
                    //breaks out of for loop, preventing continuation
                    break;
                }
            }
            //changed this because I think this is what you meant, previously it didn't make any sense since you weren't assigning anything to executionResult
            executionResult.AggregateResults = aggregateResults.AsReadOnly();


            return executionResult;
        }
```

Comment: Problem with this is if i get error in my Subvariants[0] still it is going forward which i dont want.If there is error in the first record than it should not go forward

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You want it to break entirely when there is an error and return the results up to that error and not continue on? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes correct.When there is an error i dont want to proceed further

Comment: Updated, that should do it.